# How to Set a Lightning path for a particular profile?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps, lightning-design-system

I am Faceing a issue while setting a lightning app builder path for a particular profile[image]

Here Inventor Disclosre for Inventor is a path which i have created for one pforile and Invention Disclosure Admin is another path which created for Admin,

I am Facing a problem here, when ever i am trying to use Inventor Disclosre for Inventor path i am getting Invention Disclosure Admin path.

Comment: Ho do you "try to use" the path? try creating a new record page and over there use the path

Comment: I tried by creating a New record page also..but no result

Comment: did you activate it correctly?

Comment: yes i have activated correctly.